# AndEngine: collision between shapes

Tags: android, andengine

When checking shapes collision with andengine, I usually use:

```
//set new position for the shape
mySecondShape.setPosition(mySecondShape.getX() + x, mySecondShape.getY() + y);   

//check collision
if(myFirstShape.collidesWith(mySecondShape))
```

I want to know if 2 shapes will collide before setting the new position, like :

```
if(myFirstShape.collidesWith(mySecondShape, addToX, addToY))
```

does a such method exist ?
Thank you for reading

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think such a method exists.

You can:

- Create a dummy shape - same size and everything, but invisible. Then, you could move this dummy and check for collision before moving the real shape.
- If you react to the collision right after moving the shape, it shouldn't be a problem - AndEngine won't draw the shape while your code executes (If it runs on the UpdateThread).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have tried this method but I have many shapes and application crashes sometimes with old smartphones. If I find a better one, I will post it here. Thank you for your help Jong.